# Is there a reason not to delete the System.Collections namespace in Unity3D?

Tags: unity, c#

I find various scripts on tutorials, books and even on the [community wiki](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=FramesPerSecond) `using` the `System.collections` namespace without ever actually *using* it.

Is this an obscure Unity3D requirement, or are the authors using the default script template and forget/don't bother deleting the import?

Comment: For context, the `Systems.Collections` namespace is included by default to make it easy to use coroutines, which rely on the `Systems.Collections.IEnumerator` type. It's not needed if you're not using coroutines, but leaving it there saves a bit of typing should you ever decide to add one.

Comment: This is very helpful, I've probably rushed into editing it out of the default template. I'm new to Unity and I haven't used any coroutines yet. You should consider editing this titbit of information into the accepted answer.

Comment: CTRL-. to auto-include when red squiggly appears in Visual Studio, should you delete it and end up needing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only statement that is truly required is the `UnityEngine` as that allows you to use the Unity specific classes and systems (`Vector3`, `Input`, Collides, GUI elements, particle systems, etc.). You can delete the other one if you wish, it won't affect anything (as long as it's not used, [see co-routines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)) and in some cases you might not even needed the Unity engine but thats for a different question :)

The reason that you see some using statements at the top of new files is because Unity thinks that it might come in handy for you to have them before you start. They allow you to use slightly more advanced parts of the language than is strictly needed (Array lists, Dictionaries, Queues, etc.).

Though development you will add quite a few extra `using` statements to your code that won't be needed by the end as the project develops, so you **can** delete them without it affecting the performance of the project your working on at all. In fact there are several benefits to deleting the `using` statements that aren't used:

1. The code will take a **shorter period of time to compile**, that small lag that appears when you move from your code to the unity window when the engine looks at the new code and interprets it,as there are less files to look through and build.
2. The built project will be **smaller**, This isn't really a concern for games that run on platforms with lots of space (PC, Console, etc.) but it might be useful to shave a few MB from the size of mobile games (`using system` is usually a culprit)
3. **Cleaner code**, not really an actual advantage to the player/user of the end product but I have found that going though each script as the project develops can make you think about how your code looks and might get you to make a small improvements to the structure to make it easier to read, debug and update when you look at it again.

Just make sure that each class has what it needs otherwise you will get a lot of errors, but they are easy to fixed by just adding in the bits that are used in that piece of code.

Comment: I was seeing the warning in ST3 with OmniSharp and I wondered if there was a Unity C# specific requirement that it didn't cover. I usually delete superfluous `using` statements to have a cleaner code base, like you said. Thanks for clearing this out for me, I 've already edited the default template!

Comment: I note that @DeX3r deleted their answer, but [information I'm finding](http://stackoverflow.com/a/136285/3064164) [agrees with them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7217848/3064164) that unnecessary using statements do not contribute to build size, contrary to this answer. There may be a slight difference in compile time, but I've never observed System.Collections to add any noticeable lag. Also, a user wanting lists, dictionaries, queues etc would probably want the `Systems.Collections.Generic` versions for strong typing, so as noted above I think this using is primarily included for coroutines.

Comment: Well you say that it doesn't contribute to build size but i've had occasions where i've reduced it by 15MB. If you remove a using statement in one class but still use it in another it is still added to the built project but if that was the only occurrence and you just removed it there is no point in the compiler adding it to the build. Maybe that's what you found in your research...

Comment: If nothing in your code makes use of a using statements then it does not affect the build size only thing you get from removing them is cleaner looking code. ArrayList is also very bad and no one should be using or writing about it!